# Using dplyr inside a function with an argument named like a column in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

Could someone explain why f1 behaves differently than f2 in this example:

```r
library(dplyr)

f1 <- function(data, year){
  data %>% 
    filter(year == year)
}

f2 <- function(data, y){
  data %>% 
    filter(year == y)
}

f3 <- function(data, year){
  data %>% 
    filter(!!year == year)
}


df <- data.frame(year = 2000:2005)

f1(df, 2005)
#>   year
#> 1 2000
#> 2 2001
#> 3 2002
#> 4 2003
#> 5 2004
#> 6 2005
f2(df, 2005)
#>   year
#> 1 2005
f3(df, 2005)
#>   year
#> 1 2005
```

I know this has something to do with tidy evaluation and I had a look at the vignette on [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). But the example here seems somewhat different.

I see that the problem can be fixed by using !! in f3, but I am not entirely sure what happens here.  I would be interested to know if this is the optimal solution to the problem and if it is recommended to always use !! in similar situations.

Comment: It's because your argument has the same name than your columns, so in the first example you are doing filter(data, 2005 = 2005)

Comment: `filter()` looks for column names first, and other variables afterwards.  If it finds a match it won't keep looking. So in your `f1` it's saying "filter this data as long as the contents of the column 'year' matches the contents of the column 'year', which of course it does.   In `f3` the `!!` can be thought of as specifying "the contents of the variable..."  so it filters where "the contents of the column year matches the contents of the variable year".  [link to technical explanation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#unquoting-one-argument)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. That's really useful. Is there way to make sure that the second `year` in `year == year` is interpreted explicitly as an env-variable and *not* as a data-variable?